# How to extract architecture part from kernel naming

Tags: linux-kernel, version

I kept bumping into it all the time, only now when I need it I can't find it anywhere! What architecture is the kernel of my machine?

> 2.6.18-194.el5

Comment: runnign uname with the -a flag should give you more information `uname -a` gives me  `Linux pc-name 2.6.35-23-generic #41~lucid1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 2 22:30:17 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux`

Comment: it sure did - make that official, i'll take it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running uname with the -a flag should give you more information

`uname -a` gives me

`Linux pc-name 2.6.35-23-generic #41~lucid1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 2 22:30:17 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux`

If you look around in the uname man pages There are other flags that will let you extract the arch only.

`uname -m` (for machine) gives me `i686` although not all of the flags will give you meaningful results on all systems, `uname -i` and `uname -p`  (for "hardware platform" and "processor" )both give me `unkown` if you need to do it programmatically, you will probably be better off parsing the `uname -a` output.

Comment: want some more rep ? i have just popped up another question around here :D